# How to pass NSManagedObjectContext to ViewController embedded in NavigationController & tabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am having a problem setting up an `NSManagedObjectContext` to one of my view controllers - `LibraryTrackTimeViewController`. I am attaching a screenshot (i hope that is not against the rules here) to make it clearer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ixp.jpg

As you can see - it is embedded in a `NavigationController` as well as a `tabBarContoller`. I am setting up the `NSManagedObjectContext` for the other viewControllers in `appDelegate`:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

TagLibraryViewController *tagLibraryViewController = (TagLibraryViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
tagLibraryViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];

LibrariesViewController *librariesViewController = (LibrariesViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
librariesViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

MapViewController *mapViewController = (MapViewController *)[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
mapViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

return YES;
```

}

The other view controllers it is easy to pass the `managedObjectContext` - but I am having trouble wrapping my ahead around how I can send it to my `LibraryTrackTimeViewController` because it is embedded.. Any help or advice you can give me- that would be awesome! Is there a better way of sending the `objectContexts` to my view controllers?

Comment: According to your diagram the `LibraryTrackTimeViewController` is being pushed from the `MapViewController` so why can't you just pass the Map View Controller's Managed Object Context to it?

Answer (score 2):

If you find it too complicated you can expose the context from the app delegate

```
// AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

and then get it directly from the delegate:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

This is not a recommendation - I would also recommend that you pass the context to the controllers. But it is a perfectly valid design pattern, so you can use it if you find it easier.